# apache poi word to html conversion - words boundry

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, openxml, docx

I am using below code to convert word to html file

```
    public Map convert(String wordDocPath, String htmlPath,
        Map conversionParams)
{
    log.info("Converting word file "+wordDocPath)
    try
    {
        String workingFolder = "C:\temp"
        File workingFolderFile = new File(workingFolder)

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(wordDocPath);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create().URIResolver(new FileURIResolver(workingFolderFile));
        options.setExtractor(new FileImageExtractor(workingFolderFile))
        File htmlFile = new File(htmlPath);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(htmlFile)
        XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

        log.info("Converted to HTML file "+htmlPath)

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Exception :"+e.getMessage(),e)
    }
}
```

The code is properly generating html output.

I need to put some parameters in the doc like `[[AGENT_NAME]]` that I will replace with regex later in code. But apache poi is not treating this pattern as single word and sometime splitting "[[", "AGENT_NAME" & "]]" and inserting some  tags with styles in between. I cannot write regex and replace the parameters because of it.

How does apache poi decides word boundry? is there a way to control it?

Comment: Apache POI doesn't decide on Word boundaries, it'll be Microsoft word's choice when generating the original file...

Comment: Can explain more on it? Any link will be helpful. Is there any special character that is part of word boundry?

Comment: Debugging the code (XWPFDocument.paragraphs) and going through OpenOffice specifications http://officeopenxml.com/WPparagraph.php, I got some understanding that MsWord can split text into runs anywhere in the doc. It can even split a plain continuous text not containing any special characters ( like AGENTNAME ) also. But can we control this behaviour? How to make a text be considered as one single run?

Comment: You'd have to ring up Microsoft to get the "proper" answer. Usually though, highlighting the text you want to be continuous in Word, explicitly formatting it to a different style, then formatting it back, will cause word to put that text into its own run

Comment: I tried with both highlighting and formatting (italics), still it is getting splitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the efforts, I finally decided to write code to parse word doc and merge splitted runs. Here is the code, hope it will help someone else

**Note: I have used pattern as `${pattern}`**

```
void mergeSplittedPatterns(XWPFDocument document)
{
    List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.paragraphs

    for(XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs)
    {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns()

        int firstCharRun,closingCharRun
        boolean firstCharFound = false;
        boolean secondCharFoundImmediately = false;
        boolean closingCharFound = false;
        boolean gotoNextRun = true

        boolean scan = (runs!=null && runs.size()>0)
        int index = 0

        while(scan)
        {
            gotoNextRun = true;
            XWPFRun run = runs.get(index)
            String runText = run.getText(0)
            if(runText!=null)
                for (int i = 0; i < runText.length(); i++)
            {
                char character = runText.charAt(i);

                if(secondCharFoundImmediately)
                {
                    closingCharFound = (character=="}")
                    if(closingCharFound)
                    {
                        closingCharRun = index

                        if(firstCharRun==closingCharRun)
                        {
                            firstCharFound = secondCharFoundImmediately = closingCharFound = false
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String mergedText= ""
                            for(int j=firstCharRun;j<=closingCharRun;j++)
                            {
                                mergedText += runs.get(j).getText(0)
                            }
                            runs.get(firstCharRun).setText(mergedText,0)

                            for(int j=closingCharRun;j>firstCharRun;j--)
                            {
                                paragraph.removeRun(j)
                            }
                            firstCharFound = secondCharFoundImmediately = closingCharFound = gotoNextRun = false
                            index = firstCharRun
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(firstCharFound)
                {
                    secondCharFoundImmediately = (character=="{")
                    if(!secondCharFoundImmediately)
                    {
                        firstCharFound = secondCharFoundImmediately = closingCharFound = false
                    }
                }
                else if(character=="\$")
                {
                    firstCharFound = true;
                    firstCharRun = index
                }
            }

            if(gotoNextRun)
            {
                index++;
            }

            if(index>=runs.size())
            {
                scan = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```